# Is a defaulted move constructor considered user-declared?

Tags: c++, c++11

The question is as my title states.

I'm asking because I have a class with a defaulted move constructor but code trying to perform copy assignment is failing stating that the copy assignment operator is *deleted* (according to Visual Studio 2015).

So I checked the rules [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) for implicitly declared copy assignment operators:

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted copy assignment operator for class T is defined as deleted in any of the following is true:
>
> - ...
> - **T has a user-declared move constructor**
> - T has a user-declared move assignment operator

So basically I'm not sure if a *defaulted* move constructor counts as *user-declared*. My gut tells me yes but when it comes to standardese I always like to be sure since assumptions can be costly.

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Praetorian Fair enough. Why does VS2015 complain? When I remove my defaulted move constructor, code compiles fine.

Comment: Presumably your class contains data members that are all copy assignable. When you remove the user-declared move constructor there is nothing preventing implicit declaration of a copy assignment operator

Comment: IMHO, the real question ought to be *why* a *user-declared*, as opposed to *user-provided*, move constructor prevents implicit declaration of a copy constructor. The rule also applies to user-declared destructors, and it gets annoying when you want a `virtual` destructor for instance.

Comment: @Praetorian How did you avoid the character limit?

Comment: For completeness, my class has the following defaulted: default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor. Nothing else.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Zero width space

Comment: @0x499602D2 you probably need 51540 rep ....

Comment: Ah you changed my question around so your 'yes' was really a 'no' before? I'm confused now. Can you edit your first comment to make your answer clear (or better yet, *post an answer*)

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood then. Isn't your question why having `T(T&&) = default;` results in the implicit `operator=(T const&)` being defined as deleted? If so, that's because of the clause you have in bold. The explicitly defaulted move constructor is considered *user-declared*. I'm not posting an answer because I've never been able to find a good definition of *user-declared* in the standard.

Comment: Why not just follow the Rule of Five and explicitly declare move as well as copy and the latter?

Comment: @Praetorian You are understanding correctly. Is there no distinction between *user-declared* and *user-provided* in the standard, as you had mentioned before? In a backalley kind of way, I thought one of the benefits of `default` was that you aren't *technically* declaring anything (not beyond what the compiler would have done anyway). `default`, IMHO, is just a way to tell the compiler to forcibly implicitly declare something.

Comment: To clarify, you *can* make the defaulted version different from what an actual compiler-declared version would be (e.g. `virtual` and exception specifications, IIRC), but that shouldn't change the general semantics.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28963577/576911

Comment: @void.pointer No, there's definitely a difference between *user-declared* and *user-provided*. *A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.* Your move constructor is user-declared, not user-provided.

Comment: "user-declared" means that your code contains a line which declares that function.  (Even if you put `= default` on the end).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard says:

> 12.8 Copying and moving class objects  [class.copy]
>
> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class
>   definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor
>   is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has
>   a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor.
>
> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If
>   the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy
>   assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor.

Your class has defaulted move constructor, but it is explicitly declared.
So according to standard implicitly declared copy constructor and copy assignment operator is defined as deleted.

> 8.4.2  Explicitly-defaulted functions [dcl.fct.def.default]
>
> Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are collectively called defaulted functions, and the implementation shall provide implicit definitions for them (12.1 12.4, 12.8), which might mean defining them as deleted. A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. A user-provided explicitly-defaulted function  (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly defaulted.

Using this terminology your move constructor is user-declared, but not user-provided.

Comment: The question is about copy *assignment*, not copy *construction*. My class already has a defaulted copy constructor.

Comment: The same goes for assignment operator. Added citation  about it.

Answer (score 0):

A defaulted special member function is user-*declared* but it is also *defined* by the user as defaulted. The standard doesn't explicitly define the term "user-declared" but it essentially means any special member function that has to be written out by the user. So the following declares a constructor and defines it as defaulted.

```
struct X { 
    X() = default; // declaration and definition
};
```

Defining a member function as defaulted means the *definition* is equivalent to the implicit definition. It is user-declared by virtue of the fact that it had to be typed out by the user.